# A better general definition of a predicate

Tags: functions, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

What's a better definition for (an interpretation of) a predicate *in general* (i.e. non-theory-specifically):

```
(1) a proposition-valued function.
(2) a proposition-valued function w/ a nonempty domain.
```

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Empty_domains) suggests (2), while [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28mathematical_logic%29#Formal_definition) suggests (1). (1) seems to imply the principle of propositions-as-predicates, which makes sense if we view predicate logic as a generalization of propositional logic. (You may  suggest better definitions if you have one)

Comment: You can't get a definition _in general_, because different definitions are needed in different contexts. In formal predicate logic a "predicate" is simply a symbol that combines $n$ "terms" into one "atomic formula" -- and if it means anything that's up to the axioms to tell us about. An _interpretation_ of a predicate symbol in a particular structure is a set of $n$-tuples of individuals; but you could also view that as a function form _all_ $n$-tuples of individuals to {true,false}$. If depends on what is most convenient for the task at hand.

Comment: I don't understand. Let $\mathbf{Bool}$ denote the set $\{\mathrm{true},\mathrm{false}\}$. What's the problem with defining a predicate on a set $X$ as a function $X \rightarrow \mathbf{Bool}$? I think your question needs to address this, and explain to the reader your motivation, if you want to get a useful answer.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: Thanks, I specified that the question was about  defining a general interpretation of a predicate. (I'm not entirely convinced that you cannot have a better general definition in this sense here -- let's see what others say)

Comment: @goblin: I tried to give a general (and vague) definition that makes sense in most contexts, even when truth values are not boolean.

Comment: @goblin: A good point. Perhaps we should generalize (1), (2) to cover Bool-valued functions? As I said, better definitions are welcome. It may be the case, though, that Bool-valued functions are usually not _defined_ as predicates but can play an equivalent role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the changed question, about the **interpretation** of predicate symbols instead of about predicates, in general it is a function from the domain to the collection of truth values. The domain need not be non-empty (that is peculiar to the conventional definition of first-order logic but not always assumed so), and the truth-values may not be two (such as in 3-valued logic).

Note that this definition is implementation-agnostic; you could have defined the truth values to be $0,1$ for $\bot,\top$ respectively, in which case predicates would be the same as indicator functions on the domain. Or you could have done otherwise; the definition will just follow along.

Comment: Seems like a good general definition

Answer (score 2):

Very very generally, a predicate is something that expects zero or more **objects** as inputs and produces a **truth value as output**. Now, of course you have to specify what exactly that means.

In particular, in first-order logic here are two possible definitions of **predicates** (but you cannot choose both!):

1. Simply a (well-formed) formula. The inputs are the free variables, and the output is the truth value of the formula (in a given model).
2. An function $f$ in the meta-system based on a formula $φ$ with numbered blanks that when given terms as inputs produces a formula that is obtained by substituting each blank numbered $k$ by the $k$-th input term. Under this definition a predicate applied to terms can still have free variables.

Also, there are things called **predicate symbols**, which are just symbols that can be used in a formula by writing it with the appropriate number of terms after it, usually placed in brackets. Of course, for every predicate symbol there is a corresponding predicate (no matter which definition above you choose) that 'behaves' the same way.

But predicate symbols are not the same as predicates. However, for any first-order theory we can add in one predicate symbol for every predicate, like this:

For each $k$-input predicate $P$:

Let $p$ be a new predicate symbol.

Add the axiom $\forall x_{1..k}\ ( P(x_{1..k}) \leftrightarrow p(x_{1..k}) )$.

This can be proven to give a **conservative extension** of the original theory, meaning that any sentence over the original theory can be proven iff it can be proven over the extended theory. This is in fact how we formally justify definitions!

For example over the theory of $PA$ we can let $even$ be a new predicate symbol such that:

$\forall n\ ( even(n) \leftrightarrow \exists k\ ( n=k+k ) )$.

Since this is a conservative extension, we can now work in the extended theory and use $even$ anywhere we like without worrying that we can prove 'more' than we could before.

A similar technique can be used for formulae that 'express functions', but that's for another time!

Comment: Notice that both definitions of "predicate" work fine even in non-classical logics. Also note that predicates and predicate symbols are **very** different from their **interpretations** (in a model).

Comment: OK, so you suggest (1) very generally and (2) for FOL. (I edited my question to indicate that it was about interpretations of predicates)